# How to get application cache size in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

My application is image-based and I'm using [CachedNetworkImage](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) to handle images from network. I'd like to show users cached images size on the device and an option to clean within the app. I am able to clean the app's cache using [flutter_cache_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager).

To clean app cache:

```
await DefaultCacheManager().emptyCache();
```

There is no such function to get the app's cache size. How do I do get it?

Comment: You can get the file path and then get the size of the folder from there

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you could post it as an answer with the example code for it. If it works I'll mark it as accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: Did you get any solution? It would be great if you share it here.

Comment: I stopped looking into it as I moved on to other projects later. If you have please feel free to answer here.

Answer (score 6):

You can use dart:io package to get the cache size of your application:

```
import 'dart:io';

Future<int> getCacheSize() async {
  Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  int tempDirSize = _getSize(tempDir);
  return tempDirSize;
}

int _getSize(FileSystemEntity file) {
  if (file is File) {
    return file.lengthSync();
  } else if (file is Directory) {
    int sum = 0;
    List<FileSystemEntity> children = file.listSync();
    for (FileSystemEntity child in children) {
      sum += _getSize(child);
    }
    return sum;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: are the sum Bytes or KB?

Answer (score 0):

Try my library, I think this will solve your problem.

Just work in Android and Ios

[GetCasheSize](https://github.com/mirshahbazi/cache)

I have two methods for you:

- Get remaining free space

```
availableSpace() -> Future<String>
```

- Get all storage space of the device

```
deviceCacheSpace() -> Future<String>
```