# Read Cache Storage Size with Flutter_Cache_Manager

Tags: flutter, dart, caching, size

I'm using [Flutter_Cache_Manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager) Plugin to cache Files in my App.
Inside the App I want to display the entire Cache-Size in MB but I could not find a solution for that yet.

Does anyone know how I can read the cache size in MB?

Thanks

Comment: try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62117279/how-to-get-application-cache-size-in-flutter worked for me